# Abbreviated function template vs. function template with forwarding reference param

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, type-deduction, template-argument-deduction

What are the differences between 
**function templates with forwarding reference parameters**

```
template<typename T>
void Universal_func(T && a)
{
}
```

and **abbreviated function templates**?

```
void auto_fun(auto && a)
{
}
```

Can I replace `Universal_func` with `auto_fun`? Is `Universal_func` a of `auto_fun` or are they equal?

I have tested the below program. It seems that both are the same.

```
template<typename T>
void Universal_func(T && a)
{
}

void auto_fun(auto && a)
{
}

int main()
{
  int i;   
  const int const_i = 0; 
  const int const_ref =const_i; 
  //forwarding reference template function example  
  Universal_func(1); //call void Universal_func<int>(int&&)
  Universal_func(i);//call void Universal_func<int&>(int&):
  Universal_func(const_i); //call void Universal_func<int const&>(int const&)
  Universal_func(const_ref);//call void Universal_func<int const&>(int const&)

  //auto calls  
  auto_fun(1); //call void auto_fun<int>(int&&)
  auto_fun(i);//call void auto_fun<int&>(int&):
  auto_fun(const_i); //call void auto_fun<int const&>(int const&)
  auto_fun(const_ref);//call void auto_fun<int const&>(int const&)
  return 0;
}
```

`Universal_func` and `auto_fun` deduced and expanded to similar functions.

```
void Universal_func<int>(int&&):
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
        nop
        popq    %rbp
        ret
void Universal_func<int&>(int&):
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
        nop
        popq    %rbp
        ret
void Universal_func<int const&>(int const&):
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
        nop
        popq    %rbp
        ret
void auto_fun<int>(int&&):
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
        nop
        popq    %rbp
        ret
void auto_fun<int&>(int&):
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
        nop
        popq    %rbp
        ret
void auto_fun<int const&>(int const&):
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
        nop
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

Are there any differences? What does the standard say?

Comment: function with parameter auto is not standard C++.

Comment: @101010 It is C++14.

Comment: @Zereges No, it isn't. Lambdas can have `auto` parameters IIRC, but functions definitely not yet.

Comment: @Zereges I think in C++14, only lambda parameter lists may use `auto`.  For other functions it is at the stage of Concepts TS.

Comment: @Zereges it's for lambdas not ordinary functions.

Comment: It's not part of the C++14 mainline. Functions with auto will be likely added in C++17 as "generic functions".

Comment: Lukas, i have used gcc5.3 and -std=c++1y -O0. I think c++1y used for C++14

Comment: @Ajayyadav you're probably using a compiler with experimental Concepts  enabled . Try using switches `-std=c++14 -pedantic` to get a report about this

Comment: @Ajayyadav You ask "what standard speak", but there's no standard yet.

Comment: It is accepted by GCC as an extension (without use of -pentatic), it is not standard C++, at least not yet.

Comment: @LukášBednařík, Yes compilation failed with std=c++14 -pedantic

Comment: @101010 Is it not included in standard c++ yet? I mean not approved for C++17.

Comment: @Ajayyadav The Concepts TS is a technical specification which may get merged into C++17. Also note that the term is *function template*, not *templatized function*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`auto` in function parameters is not part of standard C++ yet, but some recent versions of GCC allow this as an extension as part of their support for the Concepts TS.

The Concepts TS refers to this construct as an *abbreviated function template* (although it used to be known as a *generic function*, which I guess was too generic a term). The rules are perhaps too large to dump into this answer, but have a look in `[dcl.fct]/16-19` in [this draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4553.pdf) for all the gory details.

Paragraph 16 provides a decent overview:

> An abbreviated function template is a function declaration whose parameter-type-list includes
>   one or more placeholders (7.1.6.4). An abbreviated function template is equivalent to a function
>   template (14.6.6) whose template-parameter-list includes one invented template-parameter for
>   each occurrence of a placeholder in the parameter-declaration-clause, in order of appearance,
>   according to the rules below. [ Note: Template parameters are also invented to deduce the
>   type of a variable or the return type of a function when the declared type contains placeholders
>   (7.1.6.4.1). — end note ]

By the rules set forth in that draft, your two definitions are functionally equivalent.

We take the function with a placeholder parameter:

```
void auto_fun(auto && a)
{
}
```

And invent a template parameter to replace it with:

```
template <typename T>
void auto_fun (T && a)
{
}
```

As you can see, this has the same signature as your function without placeholders:

```
template <typename T>
void Universal_func(T && a)
{
}
```